# Display dynamic multiple image if only present

Tags: reactjs

My backend API have mulitple file upload. User can have choice to upload one image or multiple or none. So, image array may be length 0, 1 or more.

Scenerio:

endpoint `api/v1/img/1 may have gallery img1, img2, img3`

endpoint `api/v1/img/2 may have gallery img1`

endpoint `api/v1/img/3 may have gallery null`

```
{ gallery.img_urls?.map((img, i) => (
   <div key={i}>
    <img src={img} alt="gallery" />
  </div>
))}
```

It is displaying mulitiple image. But if image isn't present it raise an error
`ref3.map is not a function`

Comment: gallery?.img_urls?.map?.((img,i)

Comment: here pls use optional chaining operator  `gallery?.img_urls?.map(img, i)`

Answer (score 1):

if don't want anything when no image or any error to render image then you can use

```
{ gallery.img_urls?.map((img, i) => (
   <div key={i}>
    <img src={img} alt="gallery" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove()" />
  </div>
))}
```

OR you can set the default image src value or also if you don't want the default image then add simply null value in src.

```
{ gallery.img_urls?.map((img, i) => (
   <div key={i}>
    <img src={img} alt="gallery" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='Default.jpg'" />
  </div>
))}
```